# Change alpha when Compose Surface is being pressed (clickable modifier)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the `clickable` modifier on `Surface` and want to create a custom indication to have the surface (along with its contents) appear with 0.5 alpha when being pressed. But it seems the indication can only be used to draw additional UI.

How do I redraw the `Surface` with 0.5 alpha when it is pressed?

```
Surface(
   modifier = Modifier.clickable(interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }, indication = CustomIndication, onClick = onClick)
    ) {

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the [**`Indication`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/Indication) parameter in the `clickable` modifier. You can use the default ripple defined by [**`rememberRipple`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ripple/package-summary#rememberRipple(kotlin.Boolean,%20androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,%20androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)) changing the color.

Something like:

```
var interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

//clickable modifier
val clickable = Modifier.clickable(
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    indication = rememberRipple(color = /* use you custom color */
       MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
) { /* update some business state here */ }


Surface(modifier = clickable){
     //...
}
```

Otherwise you can use something like:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
val backgroundAlpha = if (isPressed) 0.5f else 1f

Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.clickable(true){},
    color= MaterialTheme.colors.secondary.copy(alpha = backgroundAlpha)
) {
   //....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var isPressed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val backgroundAlpha = if (isPressed) 0.5f else 1f
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {  }
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onPress = {
                    isPressed = true
                    val success = tryAwaitRelease()
                    if (success) isPressed = false
                    else isPressed = true
                }
            )
        },
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = backgroundAlpha)
) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun AlphaSurface(){
    val isClicked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val alphaValue = if(isClicked.value) 0.5f else 1f
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                isClicked.value = isClicked.value.not() // toggle the value 
            }.fillMaxHeight().fillMaxWidth(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.copy(alpha = alphaValue )
            ) {

        }
}
```